# kotlin data class and SerializedName

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, data-class

I have a data class with the following code

```
data class MyBody(
    @SerializedName("ver") val version: Int,
    @SerializedName("TO") val methodName: String,
    @SerializedName("JR") val jsonParams: String)
```

now I need to add a new SerializedName which is "type" the problem that this new parameter should only be used in some methods not all of them

can anyone please advice ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use nullable operator.
Example:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class RouteGroup @JvmOverloads constructor(
    @SerializedName("name") var name: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("id") var id: Int? = null
)
```